# How to create a list of all possible vectors that are formed from a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a data frame called indx like this;

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 7 | 6 |

And I want to create a list of all possible vectors that are formed according to the rule that, if the 2nd column of a row is equal to the 1st column of another row, then put them in order without repeat. For example, 5 is found both at [1,2] and [5,1] positions. Then one of the vectors should be (1, 5, 3)

So the desired output is like this;

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 5 3

[[2]]
[1] 6 1 5

[[3]]
[1] 3 7 6

[[4]]
[1] 3 1 5

[[5]]
[1] 5 3 7

[[6]]
[1] 5 3 1

[[7]]
[1] 7 6 1

[[8]]
[1] 1 5 3 7

[[9]]
[1] 1 5 3 7 6

[[10]]
[1] 6 1 5 3

[[11]]
[1] 6 1 5 3 7

[[12]]
[1] 3 7 6 1
```

I have wrote the code below, but it is very far from the desired result.

```
sol1 <- c()

for(i in seq_along(indx[,1])){
  for(j in seq_along(indx[,1])){
    for(k in seq_along(indx[,1])){
      if(indx[i,1] == indx[j,2]){
        sol1[k] <- indx[i,1];
        sol1[k+1] <- indx[i,2]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know it is a confusing task. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please explain about your entries with more than three numbers?

Comment: `(1, 5, 3)` I don't understand why we have this, please clarify.

Comment: So the first row has 1 / 5 and the fifth row has 5 / 3, so you want to combine these two "links" to make 1, 5, 3?   This sounds like a network analysis question where looking at `igraph` will set you up with much more efficient algorithms for constructing all the possible paths.

Comment: With `library(igraph)`, you can start with `indx |> graph_from_data_frame() |> plot()`, you are looking for all connected subsets of this directed graph. I don't know quite how to do it, but there is probably a relatively simple answer in `igraph`.

Comment: @GregorThomas I think that's the right approach, and I have implemented it here, but it gives a few extra entries compared to the target output. I don't know if these are just omissions by the OP, or there are further constraints that aren't apparent in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reframe your problem by thinking of the numbers as nodes in a graph. Your data frame can be thought of the edgelist of a directed graph, and the result you are looking for is all simple paths (i.e. paths that don't repeat nodes) through the graph. You can easily do this using `igraph`:

```r
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(indx)
```

The graph looks like this:

```r
plot(g)
```

[image]

You can get all the simple paths as follows (removing the length-2 paths that are equivalent to the individual rows in your data frame, since you seem not to want these in the output)

```r
res <- lapply(unique(as.character(indx[[1]])), function(x) {
  p <- all_simple_paths(g, x) |> 
    lapply(\(y) names(y) |> as.numeric())
  p[lengths(p) > 2]
  })

res <- unique(do.call("c", res))
```

The result looks like this (note that there are a few you have missed in your example output):

```
res
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 5 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 5 3 7
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 5 3 7 6
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 6 1 5
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 6 1 5 3
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 6 1 5 3 7
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 3 1 5
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 3 7 6
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 3 7 6 1
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 3 7 6 1 5
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> [1] 5 3 1
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> [1] 5 3 7
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> [1] 5 3 7 6
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] 5 3 7 6 1
#> 
#> [[15]]
#> [1] 7 6 1
#> 
#> [[16]]
#> [1] 7 6 1 5
#> 
#> [[17]]
#> [1] 7 6 1 5 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out how your obtained the 8th to the 12th entries in your desired list, but the `left_join` approach can help you find the first 7 linked values

```
df %>%
    left_join(df, by = join_by(C2 == C1), relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
    unname() %>%
    asplit(1)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 5 3

[[2]]
[1] 6 1 5

[[3]]
[1] 3 7 6

[[4]]
[1] 3 1 5

[[5]]
[1] 5 3 7

[[6]]
[1] 5 3 1

[[7]]
[1] 7 6 1
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(C1 = c(1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L), C2 = c(5L, 1L,
7L, 1L, 3L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```